# Why is DataTable not displaying my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have an array of objects with 2 entries. DataTable gives now error but won't display table. I have similiar construct that seem to work fine but for some reason this one doesn't:
HTML:

```
<form id=rparesponses class="hideme rpadealers">
    <table id="responseTbl" class="table table-striped table-border">

    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Dealer Email</th>
      <th>MesgID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Accept CC</th>
      <th>Delivery</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
      <th>Place Order</th>
    </tr>
     </thead>

   </table>
 </form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function displayResponses(responses)
         {

         //  var count=rpaResponses.length;
          alert("responses.name: "+responses[0].name);

           $('#responseTbl').DataTable({
            data:    responses,
                 'sort': false,
                 'searching': false,
                 'paging': true,
            columns:
             [
              {'data': 'email'},
              {'data': 'mesgid'},
              {'data': 'name'},
              {'data': 'description'},               
              {'data': 'price'},
              {'data': 'ccard'},
              {'data': 'delivery'},
              {'data': 'rating'},
              {'data': 'order'}
             ],
            columnDefs:
             [
              {'targets': 6,
                'render': function(data,type,full,meta)
                {
                 var pform='<form action="javascript: this.preventDefault"><select name="deliver"><option value="Pickup">Pickup</option><option value="Delivery">Delivery</option></select></form>';

                 if(data)
                   return data;
                 else return pform;
                  }
              },

              {'targets': 8,
                  'render': function(data,type,full,meta)
                  {

                  return '<button id="order" type="" class="btn btn-primary btn-details">Order</button>';

                  }
               }
            ]

           });

         }  //end of display responses
```

**The call to displayResponses is**

```
socket.on('rparesponse', function(data)
          {

           var rpaResponses=JSON.parse(data);

          alert("rpaResponses.length: "+rpaResponses.length);
          alert("rpaResponses.name: "+rpaResponses[0].name);

        if(rpaResponses.length>0)
             localStorage.messageid="";

          displayResponses(rpaResponses);

           $('#dealers').hide();
           $('#rpaResponses').show();
           $('#rpaview').hide();
           $('#rpawait').hide();


          });
```

**Using Devtools,** I can confirm that the passed arg "responses" is an array of objects. See below:

```
 rpaResponses: Array[2]
    0
    :
    Object
    ccard
    :
    "true"
    delivery
    :
    "false"
    description
    :
    "Fan Belt for BMW-x5 2012 model e"
    email
    :
    "bert123@mymail.com"
    mesgid
    :
    "ccc89e"
    name
    :
    "Peters Auto "
    order
    :
    false
    price
    :
    "6000"
    rating
    :
    "5"
    __proto__
    :
    Object
    1
    :
    Object
    ccard
    :
    "true"
    delivery
    :
    "false"
    description
    :
    "Fan Belt for BMW-x5 2012 model e"
    email
    :
    "peter123@gmail.com"
    mesgid
    :
    "ccc89e"
    name
    :
    "Peters Auto "
    order
    :
    false
    price
    :
    "5000"
    rating
    :
    "5"
    __proto__
    :
    Object
    length
    :
    2
```

I am using Chrome 54.28... the same problem in Firefox. I am using nodejs, socketio, javascript and jquery.....the server side is ok it sent the table across the socket ok...JSON.stringified then JSON.parse on arrival. I have also checked the SO previous questions on this subject...none apply.

can anyone show me what my error is?....maybe my eyes are going!...did I say I am new to all this!...I am.

Comment: @offir Peer...adding the tbody tag didn't solve the problem. I knew it wouldn't because I have other tables that worked without it....also that answer wasn't accepted as a solution

Comment: @offir Peer....I watched this video before and watched it again..except for the Ajax source...I am doing nothing different...also note in that video they dont use the tbody tag. I believe the problem is how datatTable view the data source (json, arrays, objects etc). I saw one recommendation that data source must be an array of objects. Well my data source is an array of objects...is there a way to tell dataTable this? like how its done in Ajax?

Comment: @OffirPe'er....I also suspect some inconsistency in DataTables because as i said before I have the very same construct working ....actually in the same HTML ...it's the #dealers that I hide when I show this table....

Comment: @offir Peer....sorry not yet that sophisticated....don't know what fiddle is only seen its use

Comment: @OffirPe'er.....problem solved...your eyes are has bad as mine....there was a syntax error on the $(#rpaResponse).show....it should have been $(#rparesponse).show......your comment above made me take a good look....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error...change $(#rpaResponse).show to $(#rparesponse).show.